# Read stored procedure with Unit of Work using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am using UOW in an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core. When trying to read values from a stored procedure with UOW the `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery` method is not found.

Currently I'm using EF Core 5 and .NET 5.

This is my `IRepository` interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkIntegrado
{
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
    Task BeginTransactionAsync();
    Task RollBackAsync();
    Task CommitAsync();
    Task<List<T>> GetSP<T>() where T : class;
}
```

My UOW implementation:

```
public class UnitOfWorkIntegrado : IUnitOfWorkIntegrado
{
    public Task<List<T>> GetSP<T>() where T : class
    {
        // SqlQuery does not appear as a method   
        return dbContext.Database
                        .SqlQuery<T>(spQuery, parameters).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

How can I implement this pattern?

Comment: .NET uses dependecy injection. You need to inject the dataContext as a service. It has to be registered in Startup.cs as a service as well.

Comment: That's right, there is no such method - `SqlQuery`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-5.0#extension-methods). There are methods `ExecuteSqlRaw`, `ExecuteSqlInterpolated`.